# Cloud Streaming To Android

Tags: java, android, streaming, cloud, ondemand

I'm Attempting to develop my first useful android app, but I need some insight.

The basic function of the app is to allow the user to access the audio files on my private server and stream them on demand (non-live).

Sort of like Pandora, as so the user doesn't have to wait for the whole file to download, and so the file doesn't take up space on the device.

The app will used to stream pre-recorded services from my church.

My questions are:

1. what is the cleanest way to access the files on the server?
2. will the server need any software, or will linking strait to the file work?
3. can android do this natively? Or is there a library to do this?

Any other insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in a simple way from a PC using IIS and a simple AsyncPlayer or MediaPlayer based app on an Android device.

See my answer to this question here...[Developing a Streaming Server for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559468/developing-a-streaming-server-for-android/5560239#5560239)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a good chance you are already finished.

Are the audio files on a web server?  If you navigate to them using the Android browser, and they are the right kind of files, then Android will play them.

If your parishioners want a separate App, you can give them a shortcut to put that just starts the browser.

Mind you, I haven't actually done this, but I think it will be pretty easy.  Everything you need is more-or-less built-in.

Same goes for iPhone.