# Network Protocol for streaming Media to Android Phone?

Tags: android, streaming, network-protocols

According to [Android developers site](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html). Android supports RTSP & HTTP progressive download protocols.
So my question is which of them is preferable to be used in the case of wanting to stream media (Audio/Video) from my pc at home.
Taking in consideration the Android Phone will be connected to internet through 3G network.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here [Developing A Streaming Server For Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559468/developing-a-streaming-server-for-android/5560239#5560239). This simply uses IIS as the server but you could easily develop it further perhaps with your own HTTP-based service.

This is the simplest approach as you don't need to host an RTP/RTSP service on your PC. It's also the most universal as all network providers should allow your client to use HTTP but use of RTP/RTSP isn't guaranteed.